# making an iphone cube class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es, xcode4

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial) and I'm currently trying to create a class to draw cubes. The class populates the buffers in a function called setup and draws them in a function called draw.

There are no errors however nothing is displayed on the screen.

My question is basicly how do I go about making a class from which I can render cubes.

Using Xcode 4.2, Opengl and Objective-C.

[edit]

```
-(void)SetShader:(GLuint)InShader
{
glUseProgram(InShader);

_positionSlot = glGetAttribLocation(InShader, "Position");
_colorSlot = glGetAttribLocation(InShader, "SourceColor");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_positionSlot);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_colorSlot);

_projectionUniform = glGetUniformLocation(InShader, "Projection");
_modelViewUniform = glGetUniformLocation(InShader, "Modelview");

_texCoordSlot = glGetAttribLocation(InShader, "TexCoordIn");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_texCoordSlot);
_textureUniform = glGetUniformLocation(InShader, "Texture");  
}

-(void)SetupVBO
{
    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(CubeVertices), CubeVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint indexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(CubeIndices), CubeIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

-(void)draw
{
glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(_colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float) * 3));

glVertexAttribPointer(_texCoordSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 
                      sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float) * 7));    

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(CubeIndices)/sizeof(CubeIndices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);  
}

-(void)render:(CADisplayLink*)displayLink 
{
glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

CC3GLMatrix *projection = [CC3GLMatrix matrix];
float h = 4.0f * self.frame.size.height / self.frame.size.width;
[projection populateFromFrustumLeft:-2 andRight:2 andBottom:-h/2 andTop:h/2 andNear:4 andFar:10];
glUniformMatrix4fv(_projectionUniform, 1, 0, projection.glMatrix);

CC3GLMatrix *modelView = [CC3GLMatrix matrix];
[modelView populateFromTranslation:CC3VectorMake(0, 0, -7)];
[modelView translateBy:CC3VectorMake(0,5,0)];
glUniformMatrix4fv(_modelViewUniform, 1, 0, modelView.glMatrix);

glViewport(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

[m_cube draw];

[_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

Comment: The question is vague. Does following the tutorial without any changes work for you? If so, what changes did you make that aren't working? In general, when OpenGL draws nothing, it's because the OpenGL state machine is set up weirdly. If you post some code showing how you're setting things up, particularly your calls to `glViewport ()`, `glOrtho ()`, `gluPerspective ()`, and/or `glFrustum ()`, that would be helpful.

Comment: I've posted some of my relevent code

Comment: Sorry should have said, following the tutorial without any changes works fine, my problem arises when I try to split aspects into their own classes. Like drawing the cube for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as mentioned a problem with the arrangement of my viewport and perspective setups.